# Remove empty space and string at a string

Tags: regex, pyspark, regexp-replace

In rows that have values like:

```
' ,some value, some value,'
```

or

```
'some value, some value, '
```

Using pyspark, I need to remove the empty space and `,` from either the beginning or the end of the string. How is this done with `regexp_replace`?

Comment: please show expected output. What did you try ?

Answer (score 0):

In PySpark, `DataFrame.fillna() or DataFrameNaFunctions.fill()` is used
to replace `NULL`/`None` values on all or selected multiple `DataFrame`
columns with either zero(0), empty string, space, or any constant
literal values.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex `F.regexp_replace("text", r"(^[\s,]*|[\s,]*$)", "")`.

Full working exmaple:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        [" ,some value, some value,"],
        ["some value, some value, "]
    ],
    ["text"]
)

[Out]:
+-------------------------+
|text                     |
+-------------------------+
| ,some value, some value,|
|some value, some value,  |
+-------------------------+


df = df.withColumn("text", F.regexp_replace("text", r"(^[\s,]*|[\s,]*$)", ""))

[Out]:
+----------------------+
|text                  |
+----------------------+
|some value, some value|
|some value, some value|
+----------------------+
```